# Unable to access channel tab on Azure portal

Tags: azure, botframework

I've created a new bot with Form template from Azure Portal. When going to "channels" tab, I got a blank page and can't access or register new channels.

[image: Azure Portal screenshot]
F12 tools show an HTTP error 401 on https://dev.botframework.com/api/Account/exchangeArmToken?tenantId=.

Comment: Please note that this is working when your Azure portal is in English. Not working when portal is in French.

Comment: It's a known issue - current solution is to change the Azure portal language to English.